# copy large 'ref byte' chunks to file

Tags: c#, pinvoke

i'm struggling in my head for what's the best way of copying large data that comes from DLL as `ref byte` to a file.
since it's a video stream (or hundreds) then i don't feel so comfortable using `Marhal.Copy`/ `WriteByte` in a loop, and etc.. but something more direct.
i'm pretty stucked with that `ref byte` and unfortunately don't really have so much to do about it.
anyways, i was thinking about P/Invoke `WriteFile` but it gets `IntPtr` where the closest i could get from `ref byte` is of course `byte*` (using `fixed`).
now, i'm going to have few hundreds of this kind of stream, and each one can get to ~2Mbps.
so at the bottom line - i'm searching for an efficient way of copying `ref byte` chunks to a file (with a given array size of course).

Comment: can you not use `System.IO.Stream`?

Comment: This is a bad case of premature optimization.  Unless the machine has massive amounts of RAM, these video streams are going to quickly saturate the file system cache.  After which it can only move as fast as the disk can write.  Overhead from Marshal.Copy() just doesn't matter at all.

Comment: @HansPassant, i'm targeting this windows-service to Windows Server 2008 machines, so i want the disk speed to be my limit before my CPU. copy each buffer to managed code and then flush it to file from there sounds horrible to me, does it really have such a minor effect?
btw, i'd glad to know what's the -1 is for

Comment: Sorry, you're right about my answer: [UnmanagedMemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.unmanagedmemorystream.aspx) isn't the answer since it would still require you to make a `byte[]` or `CopyTo` to write it to a file stream.

Comment: If you want an `IntPtr` from a `ref byte`, just rewrite your `DllImport` to use `IntPtr ptr` instead of `ref byte ptr`. I would think that's a more suited signature for it anyways.

Comment: You might also consider looking into System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.

Answer (score 0):

well in case someone would be interested, and thanks to Mr. Smith, i first changed the given DllImport from `ref byte` declarations to `IntPtr`.
then i imported `WriteFile`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool WriteFile(IntPtr hFile, IntPtr lpBuffer, int NumberOfBytesToWrite, out int lpNumberOfBytesWritten, IntPtr lpOverlapped);
```

and used it as follows:

```
//somewhere in class:
tmpFileStream = new FileStream("tmp.bin", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

public void AddBuffer(IntPtr buffer, int size)
{
    int written;
    WriteFile(tmpFileStream.SafeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), buffer, size, out written, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```